# Show Information on Tooltip about the application main features

Tags: javascript, react-native, tooltip, react-native-ios

I have to show application main features on tooltip when user open the application for the very first time. I have to show 4 features in which 2 are on tab bar and 2 on two different components. So, i am facing issue in how to close the first tooltip and after closing, opening the next tooltip.On clicking next button, my next tooltip should open up. I will really appreciate if anyone of you help me out.

[image]